# Join with CASE or other alternative (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, join, case

I have 2 tables that I need to join. 
Table 1:

```
User |Country|
--------------
 a   |  NZ   |
 a   |  NZ   |
 a   |  HU   |
 a   |  IL   |
 a   |  AU   |
 a   |  AU   |
 a   |  RO   |
 a   |  NZ   |
 a   |  NZ   | 
 a   |  NZ   |
 a   |  GB   |
 a   |  GB   |
```

Table 2:

```
   User  |Country| Payment
    ----------------------
     a   |   GB  |  20
     a   |   AU  |  20
     a   |       |  30
```

The final result that I want to get is this one:

```
User | Country | Payment
--------------
 a   |   NZ    |   30
 a   |   NZ    |   30
 a   |   HU    |   30
 a   |   IL    |   30
 a   |   AU    |   20
 a   |   AU    |   20
 a   |   RO    |   30
 a   |   NZ    |   30
 a   |   NZ    |   30
 a   |   NZ    |   30
 a   |   GB    |   20
 a   |   GB    |   20
```

In the result there are 2 conditions:

1 - If the country is equal in both tables then give me the corresponding Payment, i.e. only for GB and AU in this case.

2 - If the country in table 2 is NULL then join the payment to all other countries (except GB and AU)

This thing can be done with 2 left joins, but is there a way to do it with 1? Something like CASE/IF. I looked at several examples joining with CASE, but it's not working for me.

Thanks.

Comment: for point 2, why is it `30` now? Is there any other data that you should consider it before calculating it. If yes then where is that and how can someone calculate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would imagine 2 `outer joins` would be more efficient, since you only want to use a single `join`, here's one option using a subquery and `conditional aggregation`:

```
select usr, country, coalesce(payment, defaultpayment) as payment
from (
    select t1.usr, t1.country, 
        max(case when t1.country = t2.country then payment end) payment,
        max(case when t2.country is null then payment end) defaultpayment
    from t1
       left join t2 on t1.usr = t2.usr 
    group by t1.usr, t1.country 
) t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The max(case...) is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you want "defaulting".  A `left join` is handy, in fact two.  The first matches to the country exactly; the second brings in the `NULL` value.

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.payment, t2d.payment) as payment
from t1 left join
     t2 t2
     on t1.country = t2.country left join
     t2 t2d
     on t2d.country is null;
```

This is the best way to solve the problem, because it can make use of an index on `t2(country)`.

There are other ways; for instance:

```
select t1.*
       (select t2.payment
        from t2
        where t2.country = t.country or t2.country is null
        order by (t2.country is not null) desc
       ) as payment
from t;
```

Or, you could use one explicit `join` and aggregation.  Or something cumbersome like this:

```
select t1.*, t2.payment
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.country = t2.country
union all
select t1.*, t2.payment
from t1 join
     t2
     on t2.country is null
where t.country not in (select t2.country from t2 where t2.country is not null);
```

But the version with two `left join`s is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was this one:

LEFT JOIN Countries b ON INSTR(a.geo, b.Code) <> 0

So the JOIN is possible only when the instance is matching.